# Toggle item based on value - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to have no expand '+' sign when Total is zero?

In the first screen shot, flight and travel expenses can be viewded by expanding visit Date.

I was wondering if it is possible to have no toggle or no expand sign '+' when there are no expenses as shown in second screen shot?

[image]

Comment: You cannot do that however you can hide those rows where both values are zeros.

Comment: + sign would still be there even when the rows are hidden

Comment: have your query exclude the details instead.. or does the expand also appear when there are no details?

Comment: @user1263981, If you hide the entire row the visit date will not appear thus there wouldn't be + sign for that row.

Comment: I need to display visit date

Comment: @JamieD77 How to exclude details? Flight and Travel expenses are two columns.

Comment: Have you tried to exclude rows that equal 0 something like WHERE (FlightExpense != 0 AND TravelExpense != 0)

Comment: no i can't hide them in my query because they are link to visitdate. One to many relation.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a column to the right of "visitdate", name this as "independent"

For flight expenses and travel expenses, go to Text properties,Visibility click display can be toggled by this report item and select the name of the new column you have just inserted: "independent"

For the "independent" field, go to Text properties,Visibility, click show or hide based upon an expression, click the "fx" button and input the following:
=iif(Fields!Flight_Expense.Value = 0 Or Fields!Travel_Expense.Value = 0, True,False )

Hope this helps